# Packing net of simplex

Tags: packing-and-covering, sphere-packing

For given $d$, we can define the simplex as follows,

$S=\{(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_d):x_1\geq x_2\geq \cdots\geq x_d\geq 0,\sum x_i=1\}$.

We can define the distance on $S$ as $L_1$ distance.

An $\epsilon$ packing set of $S$ is a subset of $S$, $\{P_1,P_2,\cdots,P_N:P_i\in S\}$,such that the distance between any $P_i$, $P_j$ is greater than $\epsilon$.

The question is to ask how large can $N$ be, suppose $\epsilon$ is a small constant. Can it grow exponentially as $\exp(td)$ for some constant $t$?

Comment: What are the $P_i$? Points? Facets? Polytopes?

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke $P_i$ are points in $S$.

Comment: Certainly not! You can replace each $x_j$ by the nearest integer multiple of $\frac\varepsilon d$ and get an $\varepsilon$-net of cardinality at most $p(0)+p(1)+\dots+p(d/\varepsilon)\le e^{C\sqrt {d/\varepsilon}}$ where $p$ is the partition function. The latter seems to be the correct order of growth but I haven't really checked that.

Comment: @fedja Thank you so much! Is this optimal bound, about $d$, for $\epsilon$ net?

Comment: Actually, after 10 minutes of thinking I started to suspect that it may be not. Let me try to figure it out though that will take some time...

Comment: @fedjia I suspect it would be $\exp(C\sqrt{d/(\epsilon\log d) })$.